# JQueryMobile popup not showing when appending hash to URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open a jQuery DateBox popup in my page which modifies the hash of the window so the back browser button closes the popup instead of going to the previous website in the browser history.

```
<div data-role="page" id="base-layout">
    <div data-role="content" id="my-content-layout">
        <div id="divDesde">
            <label for="divDesde" style="text-align: left;">From Date:</label>
            <input data-theme="c" name="fechaDesde" id="fechaDesde" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"enablePopup": true, "useNewStyle":true, "centerHoriz": true, "centerVert": true, "mode":"datebox", "overrideDateFormat": "%d/%m/%Y"}' value="" class="required" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div id="divHasta" class="desdeHastaDiv">
            <label for="fechaHasta" style="text-align: left;">To Date:</label>
            <input data-theme="c" name="fechaHasta" id="fechaHasta" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"enablePopup": true,"useNewStyle":true, "centerHoriz": true, "centerVert": true, "mode":"datebox", "overrideDateFormat": "%d/%m/%Y"}' value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#base-layout", function() {

        $('#fechaHasta').on('datebox', function(e, p) {
            if (p.method === 'open') {
                window.location.hash = "#fechaHasta";
            }
            if (p.method === 'close') {
                window.location.hash = '';
            }

        });
        $('#fechaDesde').on('datebox', function(e, p) {
            if (p.method === 'open') {
                window.location.hash = "#fechaDesde";
            }
            if (p.method === 'close') {
                window.location.hash = ''
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is -- modifying the hash seems to somehow screw with the popup and it doesn't open the first time you click. Actually it does open but gets automatically closed as soon as the hash is appended.

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kelmer/WUhwV/1/embedded/result/) although I can't see the hash; i guess it's not being shown because of jsFiddle layer over the page. You can click back on your browser to close the popup though. If you click on the calendar icon on the input, the first time it's not shown, if you click again it is.

Comment: do not include the hash sign (#) when setting location.hash: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: tried that on my fiddle -- didn't work either. I have to double click to get the popup to show.

Comment: if you add a delay you can see what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/WUhwV/2/. Datebox launches popup, then when hash is set the popup closes. Second time you click the hash is already set, so the popup stays open. I don't have a solution for you, but at least you can now see that changing hash causes the popup to close...

Comment: yeah, I figured that, now what I don't understand is why changing a hash is causing the popup to close... it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: changing hash causes the page to refresh, that's why the popup disappears. You can use the HTML5 history.pushState instead: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/WUhwV/6/. See api here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface. If you are supporting IE less than version 10, you will need a fall back plan...

Comment: Can I somehow prevent jquery from listening to hash changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery mobile's internal navigation model uses hashes to keep track of the page state. It listens to hash change events and when you update the hash yourself, it takes it as a page change and somehow decides to close your datebox. You can read about it under "Hash and Ajax driven page navigation" [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)

<strike>Fortunately, the solution is very simple. Just remove all of the hash updating part from your code. Since jquery mobile itself adds a hash when you click on the calendar, you can count on it to close the datebox when you click the browser back button.</strike>

--EDIT--

Okay, replacing the script with the following code seems to be working. I've checked it on my machine.

```
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#base-layout", function() {

        $('#fechaHasta').on('vmousedown', function() { 
                    window.location.hash = "fechaHasta";
        });

        $('#fechaDesde').on('vmousedown', function() { 
                    window.location.hash = "fechaHasta";
        });

        $('#fechaHasta').on('datebox', function(e, p) { 
            if ( p.method === 'close' ) {
               window.location.hash = ''
            }
        });

        $('#fechaDesde').on('datebox', function(e, p) {
            if ( p.method === 'close' ) {
               window.location.hash = ''
            }
        });
});
```

When you add the hash on the '[vmousedown](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/)' event, the calendar hasn't opened yet and jquery mobile has nothing to close at that point so you can think of this as a quick and dirty hack.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but unfortunately when using the "usepopup" option on datebox it does not modify the hash. This happens only when using the Dialog option on Datebox, but I would like to use a popup

Comment: ^ you're right. It didn't work out the way I had thought it would. But I think I have found the solution, please check my edit to the answer.

Comment: will try it now, but I fear this won't work with touch events (my web is intended for mobile devices)

Comment: turns out it does work! thanks! EDIT: I stand corrected, I keep getting the "open only with second click" effect :(

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how you're testing it? I don't have a touch device to test this right now, but you can try some of jquery's touch events instead of the vmousedown: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html